# How can I flip/rotate a PrintDocument in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, orientation, printdocument

I have a document that I want to be flipped / rotated 180 degrees when printed. 
(This is due to the orientation of label stock in the printer).

There is a property `PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.LandscapeAngle` but it is read only.

I think this property is influenced by the printer driver and therefore not 'settable'.

Is there a nice way i can rotate the print by 180 degrees without having to do anything too nasty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that depends on what you define as being "anything too nasty" :-)

The [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class has a [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) object you can use for this, which in turn has a [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform.aspx) and [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform.aspx) method that will allow you to get things where you need them to be.

It's often worth taking a copy of the graphics object before you manipulate it so you can restore it back again when you're done.

Comment: untested but sounds promising!

Comment: Have used it successfully in some PDF-wrangling code at my last employer. Alas, since I've left, I don't have access to the actual code, but its pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings_members.aspx)

Comment: But i want it 180 degrees from what Landscape is.

Comment: Can't you just turn the label stock around?

Comment: Or is it spooled rather than in a tray?

Answer (score 2):

print a form and flip/rotate a PrintDocument in VB.NET and set DefaultPageSettings to landscape

```
Dim WithEvents mPrintDocument As New PrintDocument
Dim mPrintBitMap As Bitmap
Private Sub m_PrintDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles mPrintDocument.PrintPage
    mPrintBitMap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
    mPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    ' Draw the image centered.     
    Dim lWidth As Integer = e.MarginBounds.X + (e.MarginBounds.Width - mPrintBitMap.Width) \ 2
    Dim lHeight As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Y + (e.MarginBounds.Height - mPrintBitMap.Height) \ 2

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(mPrintBitMap, lWidth, lHeight)
    ' There's only one page.   
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub
Private Sub B_print_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_print.Click
    ' Copy the form image into a bitmap.    
    mPrintBitMap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    Dim lRect As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    lRect.Width = Me.Width
    lRect.Height = Me.Height
    Me.DrawToBitmap(mPrintBitMap, lRect)
    ' Make a PrintDocument and print.    
    mPrintDocument = New PrintDocument

    mPrintDocument.Print()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried before assigning it to the printer GDI rotate the image it self? thats what i did:

```
                _currentPage = Image.FromStream((MemoryStream)_queue.Dequeue());
                pageHeight = _currentPage.Height;
                pageWidth = _currentPage.Width;

                if (pageHeight < pageWidth)
                {
                    _currentPage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    pageHeight = _currentPage.Height;
                    pageWidth = _currentPage.Width;                      

                }
```